# Pin a view to bottom of device

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a view in a stack and I would like it to stay pinned to the bottom of the phone when it is turned to landscape. Currently i have the following:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: detectOrientationForAppBar(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: new Center(
                      child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                _captureControlRowWidget()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

within this i would like the `_captureControlRowWidget` to stay fixed to the bottom of the device even when it is rotated. Here is my `_captureControlRowWidget`:

```
  Widget _captureControlRowWidget() {
    return new Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          color: Colors.black,
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.camera_alt,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                onPressed: controller != null &&
                    controller.value.isInitialized &&
                    !controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                    ? onTakePictureButtonPressed
                    : null,
              ),
              //showSwapCameraButton(),
              new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(
                  Icons.videocam,
                  color: isRecording ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                ),
                color: isRecording ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
                onPressed: controller != null &&
                    controller.value.isInitialized &&
                    !controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                    ? onVideoRecordButtonPressed
                    : onStopButtonPressed,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Ive tried a few things like using the CrossAxis and MainAxis Alignments but it always sticks to the edge of the phone that is lowest. e.g if im holding the phone in porttrait the widget is at the bottom, if i rotate the phone 90 degrees in either direction the widget should be on the right side of the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, your main `body` is a `Column`, so, as expected your control widget is below your camera preview. In landscape mode you want your control widget to be to the right of the camera preview, which means you want your main body to be a `Row`.

You can achieve this by changing the top `Column` to a `Flex` (which is a switch-selectable Row/Column).

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  bool landscape = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.landscape;
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: detectOrientationForAppBar(),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    key: _scaffoldKey,
    body: new Flex(
      direction: landscape ? Axis.horizontal : Axis.vertical,
```

You will have to make the same change in your `_captureControlRowWidget`, making its `Column`s and `Row`s into orientation sensitive `Flex`es.